# Unindex google code svn repository content from google index

Tags: seo, search-engines, google-search-console, svn

I developed a small web site and saved the code to google code repository. Everything has been running smoothly for a while until results from google code svn repository started showing up before the results from the actual website. Is there any way I could stop google from indexing google code repository content or at least make its rank lower than the web site? I am not talking sophisticated seo techniques but rather some simple settings if there are any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Google Code Search FAQ](http://www.google.com/help/faq_codesearch.html#robots):

> you can simply put a robots file in the root directory of your code package. This will work for both archives and source control repositories like CVS and Subversion. For example, to indicate you want none of your code crawled, you could add a file called `robots.txt` in the root directory with the following:
>
> ```
> User-agent: *
> Disallow: /
> ```